# Get top 5 values from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I get json from api key.
This is my json:

```
{'[{"count":27,"stem":"obama","term":"obama"},
   {"count":20,"stem":"boehner","term":"boehner"},
   {"count":4,"stem":"tax","term":"tax"},
   {"count":3,"stem":"daley","term":"daley"},
   {"count":3,"stem":"couldn","term":"couldn"},
   {"count":2,"stem":"formul","term":"formulation"}
  ]' : ' '}
```

and I want to get the top 5 values from this json. I turn this to list of dictionaries:

```
def changetodict(data):
    json_str = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(data))
    #common = json.loads(json_str)
    commonDict = dict(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(json_str)] * 2,
                                             fillvalue=""))
    print commonDict
```

This is all the code:

```
import urllib2, mediacloud, json,itertools,ast
from collections import Counter

webUrl = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.mediacloud.org/api/v2/wc/list?q=obama+AND+media_id:1&stats=1&&fq=publish_date:%5B2012-04-01T00:00:00.000Z+TO+2012-04-01T00:00:00.000Z%5D&key= ")

def changetodict(data):
    json_str = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(data))
    #common = json.loads(json_str)
    commonDict = dict(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(json_str)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
    print commonDict 

most_common_imdb_value = Counter(b['key'] for b in commonDict).most_common(1)[0]

if(webUrl.getcode()== 200):
    data = webUrl.readlines()
    changetodict(data)
else:
    print "error"
```

What do I need to change so that it will work?

Comment: can you show an example for the output you're expecting?

Comment: {"count":27,"stem":"obama","term":"obama"},{"count":20,"stem":"boehner","term":"boehner"},{"count":4,"stem":"tax","term":"tax"} @Ni.

Comment: I see only 3 items, did you mean top three?

Comment: This is just 3 items, you said top 5 values!

Comment: What madness is  this: `ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(data))`???

Comment: edit the code @Ni.

Comment: @ettanany edit the code

Comment: to remove the u' when you change to dictionry @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @adi That is a very silly way to convert unicode strings. Is there any reason you don't want `unicode`, anyway?

Comment: "*This is my JSON*" - no, that's not JSON. I can tell because JSON doesn't allow single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> items = [{"count":27,"stem":"obama","term":"obama"},{"count":20,"stem":"boehner","term":"boehner"},{"count":4,"stem":"tax","term":"tax"},{"count":3,"stem":"couldn","term":"couldn"},{"count":3,"stem":"daley","term":"daley"}]
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>> nlargest(3, items, key=lambda item: item["count"])
[{'count': 27, 'term': 'obama', 'stem': 'obama'}, {'count': 20, 'term': 'boehner', 'stem': 'boehner'}, {'count': 4, 'term': 'tax', 'stem': 'tax'}]
```

Comment: it gives me an error:   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\getdominnat.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    nlargest(3, commonDict, key=lambda item: item["count"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: have you ran this code independently and got the same result? It seems like in your code `items` is a string and not a list

Comment: when I print type(commonDict) it gives me : <type 'dict'>

Comment: run this code independently. If it works, the is a different bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your keys, there is `,}` at the end of your key, to solve that you can use:

```
import ast
from heapq import nlargest

for k in data.keys():
    k = k[:-3] + ']'
    k = ast.literal_eval(k)
    top_5 = nlargest(5, k, key=lambda i: i["count"])
    print(top_5)
```

**Edit:**

With `data` updated content, the following should be enough:

```
for k in data.keys():
    k = ast.literal_eval(k)
    top_5 = nlargest(5, k, key=lambda i: i["count"])
    print(top_5)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import ast
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>>
>>> for k in data.keys():
...     k = ast.literal_eval(k)
...     top_5 = nlargest(5, k, key=lambda i: i["count"])
...     print(top_5)
...
[{'count': 27, 'term': 'obama', 'stem': 'obama'}, {'count': 20, 'term': 'boehner', 'stem': 'boehner'}, {'count': 4, 'term': 'tax', 'stem': 'tax'}, {'count': 3, 'term': 'couldn', 'stem': 'couldn'}, {'count': 3, 'term': 'daley', 'stem': 'daley'}]
```

Comment: it gives me an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: for data, use: `data = {'[{"count":27,"stem":"obama","term":"obama"},...`

Comment: my data is a 'list' before I change it to 'dict'

Comment: for k in commonDict.keys():
        k = k[:-3] + ']'
        k = ast.literal_eval(k)
        top_5 = nlargest(5, k, key=lambda i: i["count"])
        print(top_5)

Comment: @user3488862 you got that, because `data` is now fixed in the question